# Wind noise in Fl Studio

Tags: wind, fl-studio

I just started music production one year ago in FL Studio and I am not that great. I know how to make a song but I want to make it sound a bit majestic (tsunami-like). For that I want to add a kind of build like the wind. It is called a wind white noise but i dont know how to make it. I know how to do a normal white noise but I don't like it.

How can I make white noise more like the wind?

Comment: I tried searching the internet but i came up with pageg that where not clear to me. I could not understand them

Comment: Hi Codemaster, i meant, what have you tried to do in FL studio?

Comment: I made just the normal whitenoise with 3xosc and edit them with a few chrucsers and some other editing plugins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generating a realistic wind noise is a tad hard, but this might work:

- Don't use a generator, use a recording of white noise (or pink noise, if available)
- Apply Fruity Fast LP (around %30 Cutoff and some resonance) then some EQ gain to qqmid-lows
- Adding some reverb with big room size will sweeten it
- Add pitch, cutoff and volume automation to make it sound more chaotic and natural

Voila.